# Can I customize conky to act differently on a dual display?

Tags: multiple-monitors, conky

I've got Conky set up [just the way I like it](https://gist.github.com/amandabee/7415214) on my laptop. (That's not entirely true. I might like to tweak it a bit.) but when I plug in my external monitor, I'd like different placement. Is that possible? To vary the placement of Conky depending on how many monitors I've got attached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like the answer is "no" and what I finally did was re-arrange my monitors so that Conky stays where I want it (on my laptop screen, on the left-hand side).